# How Do i read ituneslibraryXML File to rhythmbox?

Tags: rhythmbox

I have my iTunesLibraryXML File and would like rhythmbox to read and rebuild my playlist. Any Idea how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download [this](http://dwelle.org/eg/transferratingsperl.zip) file and extract it to your home folder.

Install `perl`

`sudo apt-get install perl`

Type the following command -

`perl transferratings.pl path/to/itunes.xml path/to/rhythmbdb.xml`

The location of `rhythmdb.xml` can be found using

`locate rhythmdb.xml`

Comment: locate command dont work

Comment: Could you post the error you got?